# Get a specific value in a string in plsql

Tags: plsql

I have following string and I want to get the value for $CF$_TRANSFER_ID. Here it should be 143.

String :

```
'!PARAMETER_MESSAGE
$FILE_TYPE=Dummy
$SET_ID=1
$COMPANY=ABC
$CLIENT_SERVER=C
$FILE_TEMPLATE_ID=DummyTemp
$FILE_DIRECTION_DB=2
$CF$_TRANSFER_ID=143
$PARAM_SET=TRUE
$FILE_NAME=D:\temp\file.csv'
```

any idea how I can get the value for $CF$_TRANSFER_ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_substr`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php).

But since oracle doesn't support lookaround and non capturing groups, you need to use a bunch more parameters than usual:

```sql
val := regexp_substr(my_str,'\$CF\$_TRANSFER_ID=(.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

Here:

- third param: start search from first symbol,
- forth: extract from first match,
- fifth: no modifiers (like `g` - global or `m` - multiline),
- sixth: take only the first group of match.

Comment: Thanks @markalex, it is the expected answer for me.